# Convert Groovy DSL scripts to Jenkinsfiles

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a rather large project and I'm tasked with converting current Jenkins jobs from DSL Groovy scripts into Jenkins files.  Is this done manually or can I automate to some level?  I did find some decent info on the Jenkins doc site but this is a mid-stream task so trying to find someone who has been through this before.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/

Comment: What do you mean by DSL Groovy scripts? Do you have non-pipeline Jenkins jobs that execute Groovy scripts?

Comment: I may have mis-used DSL Groovy scripts.  We have groovy scripts that run for all phases of a pipeline and its lengthy.  The task is to start implementing Jenkinsfile's to replace some of that.  Trying to understand how to make that happen from a real-world scenario outside of what I'm finding on Github, Jenkins documentation, etc.

Comment: Can you provide more info, maybe in the form of a screenshot of a minimal example of the status quo solution you're trying to move away from? I'm pretty sure you're not currently using Jenkinsfiles, but not 100% sure, and, like Ale Sequeira, I'm not totally sure how you might be running groovy in a project with no Jenkinsfile.

Comment: @burnettk I can't provide a screenshot due to the company I work for.  You are correct I'm not using Jenkinsfiles currently and not sure with the version we are on if we can use them at all.